# automatically redirect and opens a URL action in same tab- Tableau Public

Tags: url, action, dashboard, tableau-api

I am building a dashboard for Online support portal( KAYAKO) data.
And I am trying to link the data with our online support portal so that the manager/end user can view the ticket information in detail correspondingly and cross dimensionally.

I have successfully linked the data with the online support portal using the ticket ID used in data and mapping it the Ticket ID used in the URL. For that purpose I have used 'URL Action'.

This is the Link I have used in my URL Action - on select it loads the ticket information in detail which the user has selected :
https://support.elixir.com/staff/index.php?/Tickets/Ticket/View/

The issue that I am facing is that when I am using the embedded link of this dashboard ( from my Tableau Public profile) it automatically opens the Online support portal page if my user is logged in. In the same window. And it automatically resets/reload the dashboard to its original state when I go back. Also, it might get confusing for new user since his user experience will be navigated to new page without his knowledge. .

Due to this I am unable to view the information on one page/dashboard view.

However, I am able to do this correspondingly in one view in Tableau Desktop and its working perfectly fine on the Tableau Reader too.

I have done some research and tried few solutions from the Tableau Community too, but I am unable to resolve this issue.

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/set-server-views-to-open-links-in-same-window
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/setting-url-actions-to-open-in-a-new-browser-tab
https://c.na61.visual.force.com/apex/QuickFix?_ga=2.207448407.536617528.1519969568-2070359714.1508845865&id=kA432000000PKu4&lang=en_US

I have also tired using Link_target=_parent/self in my URL action link but my support portal link shows an error. Is there some way to achieve this ?
Looking forward for the help.

[image: sample of the dashboard design]

[Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oD0l.png)

Comment: I'm confused, can you clarify your problem? Based on the image of your dashboard design, you have a webpage object on the dashboard. And a URL action should put the action's destination page inside that object. What you are saying is that the Tableau Public page gets replaced entirely by the destination webpage, am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Thanks Sam for reaching out. 
Yeah Sam. I have added a URL action in Sheet 2 and a web object. Basically, Sheet 2 contains the data in which the ticket ID exists and using the URL action I am trying to integrate it the online support portal web page.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the dashboard in my org question.